# phpimage() shows blank page only

Tags: php

I've been coding PHP and all I want is to safely secure emails from robots by converting them to image datatype. Something is wrong, the webpage is actually transformed to image format but it doesn't display anything.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?
phpheader('Content-type: image/jpeg');

if (isset($_GET["email"])) {
    $email = $_GET["email"] ;
} else {
    $email = 'email not specified';
}
$email_length = strlen($email);
$font_size = 4;
$image_height = ImageFontHeight($font_size);
$image_width = ImageFontWidth($font_size) * $email_length;
$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$font_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($image, $font_size, 0, 0, $email, $font_color);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Comment: Please lay your code out properly before asking for help with it. It is barely legible in this state, and while it is your business if you want to make your job difficult, it is rather rude to  expect us to wade through stuff like that.

Comment: Firstly make sure there are no extra spaces around the <?php ?> tags, in the file you are editing, and also any included files.